# how to order data in numeric and alphabetical order depends on condition in single query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have below table

table t

```
txt        id1   id2    id3 
Whistler    1    2      11
Slim        2    1      11
Fluffy     10    1      11
Buffy      20    1      11
Claws      3     1      11
Fang       11    1      11
Bowser     31    1      11
Edward      5    2      12
Puffball    8    2      12
Chirsy      9    2      12
```

when I write below query : which get sort by 'txt' column alphabetically.

```
SELECT * FROM t 
WHERE id2=2
ORDER BY CASE   WHEN id2 = 2 THEN txt
                WHEN id2 = 1 THEN id1 
         END ASC ;
```

above query gives result like :

```
txt             id1   id2    id3 
Chirsy          9     2     12
Edward          5     2     12
Puffball        8     2     12
Whistler        1     2     11
```

Now ,if I want to sort data numerically,then I write below query.

```
 SELECT * FROM t 
 WHERE id2=1
 ORDER BY CASE  WHEN id2 = 2 THEN txt
               WHEN id2 = 1 THEN id1 
        END ASC ;
```

But above query gives me rresult like this:

```
txt      id1  id2  id3 
Fluffy   10    1    11
Fang     11    1    11
Slim     2     1    11
Buffy    20    1    11
Claws    3     1    11
Bowser   31    1    11
```

but in above result id1 column doesn't get sorted.. why?

I want output like this for above query:

desired output:

```
txt     id1   id2   id3 
Slim     2     1    11
Claws    3     1    11
Fluffy   10    1    11
Fang     11    1    11
Buffy    20    1    11
Bowser   31    1    11
```

How to write query for this.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
SELECT
  *
FROM t
WHERE id2 = 1
ORDER BY CASE
  WHEN id2 = 2 THEN txt
END ASC,
CASE
  WHEN id2 = 1 THEN id1
END ASC;
```

[image]

```
SELECT
  *
FROM t
WHERE id2 = 2
ORDER BY CASE
  WHEN id2 = 2 THEN txt
END ASC,
CASE
  WHEN id2 = 1 THEN id1
END ASC;
```

[image]